# How do I create a schema for a blog where posts belong to categories (e.g. Music, Anime, Products) & relate to different tables based on category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, reactjs, schema

I'm working on a Rails app and have made some initial migrations and associations. Here's the schema I currently have:

[Current Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKG52.png)

Right now, I'm not sure if this schema will actually work. I'm trying to include different data in my posts depending on the category (e.g. If the post is in the "Music" category, it will show the title of the record, along with the artists who created it). The way I have it now, some of the tables will have a hardcoded `category_id` (e.g. `products`, `episodes`, `records`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to include some data of a music record in your post that means that you need to create a relationships between the two tables. for example:

```
rails g migration add_record_references_to_posts record:references
```

then `rake db:migrate`

models/post.rb:

```
belongs_to :record
validates :band_type, presence: true, if: 'category.id == 2'
```

models/record.rb:

```
has_many :posts
```

This way you can choose from what record your post belongs to using a select (don't forget to add that in your form). 
You will then be able to retrieve your record title from your post for example in your post show page you can do:

```
<% if @post.category.name == "Music" %>
 <%= @post.record.title %>
 <%= @post.record.name %>
<% end %>
```

In your post form you can use jquery to show or hide the inputs specific to the post category.

I however don't think that you need the category table at all. You'll be able to know what kind of post it is depending on the presence of the post relationship with other tables (records, episodes or products). For example if the post (the object not the model) belongs to a product, you will know that it's a product's post, so you can do for example:

```
 <% if @post.record.present? %>
   <%= @post.record.title %>
   <%= @post.record.name %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: I'm using React (JSX) instead of ERBs. But how does the Post model work if I'm trying to make it so that posts belong to either a record, product, or episode based on the category?